# 419 Page expired even when I input wrong password in production mode shared hosting Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, phppresentation

I have tried everything I know cache:clear, config:clear database sessions etc. But in development mode, it works fine, but in production, it doesn't. Any ideas?

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:<available>
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://chalavfrics.com

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=chalavfrics.com
```

**session.php**

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

**app.php**

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://chalavfrics.com'),
```

Comment: change SESSION_DRIVER=file to SESSION_DRIVER=database

Comment: check Laravel log file if any error occurs then it stores in log file